# Linear fractional differential

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fractional-calculus

If we have the IVP(intial value problem) for linear fractional differential equation:
$$
{D}^{q}{x}\mathrm{{=}}\mathit{\lambda}{x}\mathrm{{+}}{f}\left({t}\right)\hspace{0.33em}\hspace{0.33em}\hspace{0.33em}{x}{\mathrm{(}}{t}{\mathrm{)(}}{t}\mathrm{{-}}{t}_{0}{\mathrm{)}}^{{1}\mathrm{{-}}{q}}\left|{}\right.\mathrm{{=}}{x}_{0}
$$

And we have the solution in the form:

$$
{x}{\mathrm{(}}{t}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{{=}}{x}^{0}{\mathrm{(}}{t}\mathrm{{-}}{t}_{0}{\mathrm{)}}^{{q}\mathrm{{-}}{1}}{E}_{q\mathrm{,}\,q}{\mathrm{(}}\mathit{\lambda}{\mathrm{(}}{t}\mathrm{{-}}{t}_{0}{\mathrm{)}}^{q}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{{+}}\mathop{\int}\limits_{{t}_{0}}\limits^{t}{{\mathrm{(}}{t}\mathrm{{-}}{s}{\mathrm{)}}^{{q}\mathrm{{-}}{1}}}{E}_{q\mathrm{,}\,q}\left[{\mathit{\lambda}{\mathrm{(}}{t}\mathrm{{-}}{s}{\mathrm{)}}^{q}}\right]{f}{\mathrm{(}}{s}{\mathrm{)}}{ds}
$$

The solution $x(t)$ is clearly unique since the IVP satisfies the Lipschitz condition.
Can someone explain to me how can we show that the solution is unique?